# specific row number with all the fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have HR oracle schema and in that, I want to display all the fields of employees who have a 3rd highest salary.

Here is what I have written so far but it does not return anything.

```
select * from (
      select * from HR.EMPLOYEES 
       order by HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY DESC) 
 where rownum=3
```

I want to get this result without using any functions like dense_rank() etc. Want to keep the query simple. But if someone can use analytic function and can explain its working then I can get the idea of its use so far I don't understand the use of functions like dense_rank(). Any idea of what I am missing in my query?

Comment: *"I want to get this result without using any functions like dense_rank() etc."* Why? Analytic functions are the simplest and most efficient way of getting this result

Comment: @APC I have read their explanation but don't know how to use it....if you can use in my query and get the outcome and explain it maybe I can get the idea. Thank you.

Comment: do you understand how aggregate queries (`group by`) work? Analytic functions aren't much more difficult than aggregate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rownum = 3` won't work because `rownum` is applied to the generated resultset. The first row in a result set always has `rownum = 1`. No resultset can match `rownum = 3` so you get no rows back.

The way to do this is with an analytic function like `rank()`, `dense_rank()`  or `row_number()`.

```
select * from 
    ( select emp.*
             , dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) rn
      from hr.employees emp
    )
where rn = 3
```

Whether to use `rank()`, `dense_rank()`  or `row_number()` depends on how you want to handle ties.

If you use `row_number()` you will get the third row in the table sorted  by salary descending. Would this be correct if you have two employees earning the highest salary? Or indeed four such lucky employees)?

If you use `rank()` the subquery will return gaps in the ranking if there are ties, e.g. 1st, 2nd=, 2nd=, 4th,  so you won't get any result for third place.

On the other hand `dense_rank()` doesn't have gaps if there are ties, e.g. 1st, 2nd=, 2nd=, 3rd. That is why I used it above.

---

For the record, the equivalent query using `rownum` would require an additional nested subquery.

```
select * from (
    select emp.*
           , rownum as rn
    from 
        ( select * from hr.employees
          order by salary desc) emp
    )
where rn = 3
```

This has the same outcome as the `row_number()` analytic solution, that is it ignores ties.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you need to determine `rownum` in a subquery without *order by* clause :

```
select * from
(
select rownum as rn, ee.* 
  from (
        select e.* from employees e order by salary desc
       ) ee
 )      
where rn=3;
```

*P.S. Using analytic functions is better as APC told*