# How to select nth row from table using rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT emp_id INTO high_payed_emp_id
FROM (SELECT emp_id  from cursor_table ORDER BY emp_salary DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

I am trying to get the emp_id of max. payed employee
**error message:ORA-00905: missing keyword**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FETCH FIRST` instead, add `WITH TIES` to get both if there are two (or more) with the same max salary:

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM cursor_table
ORDER BY emp_salary DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: For the benefit of future Seekers, this solution only works in Oracle 12c or later. People still using earlier versions should use one of the analytic functions discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757815/146325)

Answer (score 1):

Yor  need correct sql syntax

```
 insert INTO  high_payed_emp_id (emp_id)
 select * from
 (
 SELECT emp_id
 FROM cursor_table ORDER BY emp_salary DESC
  )
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Comment: The original question has no INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_id INTO high_payed_emp_id
FROM (SELECT emp_id  from cursor_table 
WHERE emp_salary = (select max(emp_salary) from cursor_table))a
```

Comment: thanks. 'a' at the end is typographical error right ?

Comment: @Durairajs Hi, it is the alias for the sub query with out that this query will give a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me the easiest approach to select the employees having max salary in Oracle:

```
select emp_id from cursor_table where emp_salary 
= (select max(emp_salary) from cursor_table)
```

Comment: Does Oracle really support that MS SQL Server `top` syntax?